# Form not submiting on chrome but in firefox submitting

Tags: javascript, php

I have a submmit button like Following:

Save & Continue

And My function in js is:

```
function checkCreditDebit(buttonValues) {
    //Some validation here

   //Disable Button if once clicked to prevent twice form submission
    document.getElementById('saveandcontinue').disabled = 'disabled';
    document.getElementById('onlysave').disabled = 'disabled';

}
```

But when i submit form in firefox it disabled the "save & continue", button and submit form. But in chrome it disable the button but not submit the form. What is the wrong with this please suggest. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Disabled <input> elements in a form will not be submitted

Comment: could you please make a fiddle..?

Comment: <button onclick="return checkCreditDebit('saveandcontinue');" id="saveandcontinue" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save & Continue</button>   Form element are not disabled. only button become disabled

Comment: Can you post your HTML code too? just the form and whats inside of it.

Comment: so you want to prevent multipple page sumbission. right?

Comment: I am unable to make a Feedle  because code is to Large. please have a look on this URL: http://yps.staging.edubold.com/login

Comment: short Name: yps email: shailendrarawat@ypschd.com pass: admin_YPS@2015

Comment: No I want to make submit button disabled when user click on "Save" button. in firefox it working but in chrome it disabled the button but form do not going to POST..

Comment: http://yps.staging.edubold.com/vouchergeneration/new. Please open this url after login

Comment: Yes,  ARUNRAJ, the purpose is to prevent multiple form submission.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    instead of disabling pervent multiple submit by setting a javascript flag example : 
    <form method="post" id="ecomFormBean" name="ecomFormBean" onsubmit="return checkSubmit(this);" >
 <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
    <script>
    var formSubmitted = false;
    function checkSubmit(f){
        if (formSubmitted) {
          alert('Please be patient. Your order may take 10 - 15 seconds to process. Thank you!');
          return false;
        }
        else return formSubmitted = true;
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: <button onclick="return checkCreditDebit('saveandcontinue');" id="saveandcontinue" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save & Continue</button> I need to call function on this only. I have some other validations to check as well..

Comment: and you attached the validation on button click? the form cannot only be submitted via button click, it can also be submitted via "enter" key.

Comment: yes all my validation working onClick(), So it is working on firefox. Unable to figureout why not on chrome..

Comment: look my friend, what I am trying to tell you is you shouldn't put the form submit handler on submit button onClick event, because it will be surpassed  if the user press the  "enter" on his/her keyboard. Put your handler on form onSubmit event instead.

Comment: we are not allowing user to submit form while pressing enter key, becuae this is account calculation form. User will not able to submit form using ENTER

Comment: yes ofcourse.. but tricky user can always open browser console, and type document.form.submit(); and Wallaaaahh! your form is submitted without triggering your onClick

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just disabling your submit button(forms can also be submitted if you press enter on text-boxes), attach a handler to your form that will leave a 'class name' to your form as a mark that the form was already submitted, if the user submit the form again, the handler should check if the form has already the class name, then prevent duplicate submission via event.preventDefault().

**try this:**

```
<form onsubmit="prevent_duplicate(event,this);" action="">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
    function prevent_duplicate(event,form)
    {
       if((" "+form.className+" ").indexOf(" submitted ") > -1)
       {
          alert("can't submit more than once!!!");
          event.preventDefault();
       }
       else
       {
           form.classList.add("submitted");
       }
   }
</script>
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/L188g4yd/11/)

Answer (score -1):

Chrome runs javascript very fast. So it might be possible your checkCreditDebit(buttonValues) function which is to disable submit button executes before your php script submits the form.

I suggest you to call setTimeOut function before calling the javascript function so that the form can get submitted.

Give it a try.